# Validation in Rails without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that allows the user to send a message to an email, and I want to add validation to it. I do not have a model for this, only a controller. How should I do this in Rails?

I was considering doing the validation in the controller, and displaying the errors to the user using the [flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html) object. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best approach would be to wrap up your pseudo-model in a class, and add the validations there. The Rails way states you shouldn't put model behavior on the controllers, the only validations there should be the ones that go with the request itself (authentication, authorization, etc.)

In Rails 2.3+, you can include `ActiveRecord::Validations`, with the little drawback that you have to define some methods the ActiveRecord layer expects. See [this post](http://www.prestonlee.com/2007/12/29/rails-20-validations-without-extending-activerecordbase/) for a deeper explanation. Code below adapted from that post:

```
require 'active_record/validations'

class Email

  attr_accessor :name, :email
  attr_accessor :errors

  def initialize(*args)
    # Create an Errors object, which is required by validations and to use some view methods.
    @errors = ActiveRecord::Errors.new(self)
  end

  # Required method stubs
  def save
  end

  def save!
  end

  def new_record?
    false
  end

  def update_attribute
  end

  # Mix in that validation goodness!
  include ActiveRecord::Validations

  # Validations! =)
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_format_of :email, :with => SOME_EMAIL_REGEXP
end
```

In Rails3, you have those [sexy validations](http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3/) at your disposal :)

Comment: Easy as pie. Thank you, where looking for something like this.

Comment: For Rails 3, replace ActiveRecord::Errors with ActiveModel::Errors

Comment: For Rails 3 or 4, one should be using `ActiveModel::Validations`. See here for details and examples: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html.

Answer (score 3):

For Rails 3+, you should use [`ActiveModel::Validations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html) to add Rails-style validations to a regular Ruby object.

From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html):

> ## Active Model Validations
>
> Provides a full validation framework to your objects.
>
> A minimal implementation could be:
>
> ```
> class Person
>   include ActiveModel::Validations
>
>   attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
>
>   validates_each :first_name, :last_name do |record, attr, value|
>     record.errors.add attr, 'starts with z.' if value.to_s[0] == ?z
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Which provides you with the full standard validation stack that you
>   know from Active Record:
>
> ```
> person = Person.new
> person.valid?                   # => true
> person.invalid?                 # => false
>
> person.first_name = 'zoolander'
> person.valid?                   # => false
> person.invalid?                 # => true
> person.errors.messages          # => {first_name:["starts with z."]}
> ```
>
> Note that `ActiveModel::Validations` automatically adds an errors method
>   to your instances initialized with a new `ActiveModel::Errors` object,
>   so there is no need for you to do this manually.