# Rails 3 form validations without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've created a contact form using form_tag and other simple non-model-related rails form helpers. The form just submits an email to the site administrator. Anyway, I'd like to validate the fields on the form, but I'm having trouble finding a Rails-friendly way of doing this.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563087/rails-validation-without-model) to what seems to be the same question, however the accepted answer didn't seem to present a clear solution for Rails 3 (it seemed more oriented toward Rails 2). Could someone provide a concise example of how to easily do client-side validation of a form not related to a model in Rails 3? Extra points for a strategy that utilizes the default Rails validators.

And let's pretend my form looks something like this:

```
<%= form_tag "/contact" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  <%= text_area_tag :message %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing the solution proposed in the question you linked to? It should work in Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

Give [active_attr](https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr) a try. Here's a short [audio description](http://ruby5.envylabs.com/episodes/249-episode-245-february-10-2012/stories/2185-activeattr-gem).

I personally haven't tried it yet, but was thinking I will in the near future.

Also, in Rails 4, you'll kind of have the same functionality of the gem included: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/03/barebone-models-to-use-with-actionpack-in-rails-4-0/. And [audio description](http://ruby5.envylabs.com/episodes/258-episode-254-march-13th-2012/stories/2267-barebone-models-with-actionpack-in-rails-4-0) :-).