# What's the best way to do form field validations for phone numbers in Rails view without using a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, phone-number, form-fields

I have the following form field in my index.html.erb view:

```
 <%= form_tag("/calls/call", :method => "post") do %>
  <br />
  <%= text_field_tag(:call_to, "Number to call") %>
  <br />
  <%= text_field_tag(:call_from, "Number to call from") %>
  <br />
  <%= submit_tag("Dial") %></a>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

I want to constrain the field to allow only 10 digit US phone numbers without using a model validation (as there is no model).

There's probably a lot of ways to do this, but what do you folks find to be the simplest to implement?

I've tried using the 'active_attr' gem, but didn't have much luck. With 'active_attr' I created a model called Call. Here's what the model looks like:

```
class Call

include ActiveAttr::Model

  attribute :call_to
  attribute :call_from

  # attr_accessible :call_to, :call_from

  validates_presence_of :call_to
  validates_presence_of :call_from
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class CallsController < ApplicationController

  def call

    call_to = params["call_to"]

    call_from = params["call_from"]

    call_to.to_i
    call_from.to_i

    puts call_to
    puts call_from

  end 

end
```

Am I supposed to instantiate an instance of a Call class in the controller or something along those lines?

```
@call = Call.new
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701418/rails-3-form-validations-without-a-model

Comment: thanks - I tried using 'active_attr', but didn't have much luck. I've updated my original post.

Answer (score -1):

One client side option would be using the HTML5 type=tel input. [Here's](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.tel.html) a link to some documentation. You will still want some server side validation though.